# MATLAB: Does there exist a smart way to remove adjacent (x,y) points stored in some array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

Does there? I am thinking specifically about some matrix array where the rows correspond to x and y coordinates, e.g.

```
4 3
4 5
5 4
3 4
4 4
```

such that (4,3) and (4,5) etc. are (x,y) points. The problem is this: If one of the points in the list is surrounded adjacently by other points in the list, e.g.

```
(~,~) (4,5) (~,~)
(3,4) (4,4) (5,4)
(~,~) (4,3) (~,~)
```

as would be the case for the list above, then I would like to remove it in some efficient manner. It is very easy to see visually if this is satisfied by some point, but how do I do it in code? I am just looking for some suggestions, so if someone has encountered this problem before or have some input I would appreciate to read it!

Best regards,

Comment: your question is unclear. what did you try, and why isnt that "efficient"  or "smart"?  (vauge terms). Is your data double or maybe uint8? how big is the array? etc...

Comment: Which of the points do you want to remove? Only the points completely surrounded by points? If two neighboring points are both surrounded by points, and you delete the first one of these, then the second one is no longer surrounded. Do you still want to remove it?

Comment: Well, what I was thinking was setting up a matrix of 1s and 0s that represent which points in my grid is occupied, then from there look at every (x,y) point if it has adjacent nejghbors. But going through a matrix like that seems expensive for my pruposes. I am doing a simulation of a forest fire, and the list of (x,y) points represents all the positions where there is a fire. Then I iterate through the list to generate more fires, but some of these positions become unecessary as time goes on (they do not affect the results any longer).

Comment: Yes that is true, I hade not thought about that. I would like all points that have adjacent neighbors to be picked out of this specific list of (x,y) points. It would be a bad idea to refer to the list on which points to remove as you implied. I also have a matrix/grid where some points are 1: and others 0:s, what i would like to do is to make the list of (x,y) points only contain those grid points that do not have four adjacent neighbors as described. All the other points shall be represented in the list. By the way, this discussion has given me an idea, I will try implement and be back.

Comment: if you have a binary matrix M, then you can use a 2D convolution to detect the connected non zero value: `M(conv2(M,[0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0],'same')>0) = 0`

Comment: That still does not answer why you think a matrix of 0 and 1 is inefficient. I am pretty sure either a full or a sparse matrix is more efficient than your current way of storing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can avoid looping here (not sure if that's what you meant by efficient anyway...). At least i didn't come up with a solution without loops off the top of my head but this should do it.

```
vec = [4 3; 4 5; 5 4; 3 4; 4 4; 6 7; 6 8; 6 6; 5 7; 7 7];
for i = 1:length(vec)
    point = vec(i,:);
    mat = vec-point;
    % Calculate diagonal values of the matrix product
    % Note that sum(mat.*mat,2) might be a bit faster. You can try yourself.
    tmp = diag(mat*mat');
    if (length(find(tmp == 1)) == 4)
        % If we find 4 values of 1 in tmp, the point is surrounded
        % E.g., remove the value here if you wish
        point
    end
end
```

edit: Also, note that this won't work properly if you have duplicate points in the vector.